# Is there a way to query a column for the number of times the current records value for that column exists?

Tags: sql, count

Is there a way to query a column for the number of times the current records value for that column exists? For the sample below the query would looks something like

```
SELECT ID, Col1, (SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 = Col1) AS Expr1
```

Sample table

```
ID | Col1
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | A
5  | B
```

Sample Output from SELECT

```
ID | Col1 | Expr1
1  | A    | 2
2  | B    | 2
3  | C    | 1
4  | A    | 2
5  | B    | 2
```

Comment: What DBMS (PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQL Server) ?

Comment: Ultimately I'll stick the query into an Access DB. I'm joining a couple of SharePoint lists and creating a pivot table from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method, using a group-by and a join operation. (this syntax should be pretty standard)

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Col1, b.Expr1
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Col1, COUNT(Col1) AS Expr1
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY Col1
) b
ON a.Col1 = b.Col1
```